# Desktop Application to show unread email

Tags: windows-10, email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

Is there a desktop application/Widget that exists to show how many unread emails you have?

I know it's a bit of an odd request as you get notifications through Outlook and most people will have Outlook open to see how many emails they have. I just need a quicker way (as I spend sometime on the desktop) to show my email count (I have 3 mailboxes too).

I've done the obvious google search, but get plastered with "How to show outlook notifications etc. etc."

Thanks!

Edit : Essentially I need something else to help me track my inboxes.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: Apologies, I will mark it as answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Outlook 2016 with around 6 different emails connected to it for the last 3 months. It works absolutely fine on my Windows 7 Ultimate x64 Lenovo z570 laptop.

When there is a new incoming email there usually appears a pop-up on top of all the windows in the bottom right corner and it stays there for about 7 seconds (you can change this time from the `Desktop Alert settings`). After this pop-up disappears there is a small icon in the `Notification area icons` showing me that there is new email.

You can see the described about behavior from from the screenshots below:

[image: Preview of the Outlook 2016 Desktop Alert Settings]

There are also multiple browser extensions for Google Chrome for ex. [Outlook.com](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/outlookcom/pfpeapihoiogbcmdmnibeplnikfnhoge?hl=en-US) and [Outlook.com Notifier App!](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/outlookcom-notifier-app/hdkoopdmeognklcjndkgcoifebihfcga?hl=en-US), but they just clone the behavior of the local Outlook app not giving you any extra functionality.

Outlook is not the only option to go there is [Thunderbird](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/) from Mozilla, but I haven't used it myself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I don't think the Desktop Alert Settings exists in Outlook 2016. They may have integrated it into Windows 10 option. Will have a look!

Comment: @SionJones I've made a screenshot from my Windows 7 machine. So Desktop Alert indeed exists in Outlook 2016.

Comment: @SionJones - Of course it exists.  The notification is something the programmer has to add to an application.  Additionally the read status of an email is something that is kept track by the client in most cases.

Comment: @Ramhound Well it's not there for me. The check option is there to turn on the Desktop alert, but there is no option to change how long the notification stays up for, as alljamin made a screenshot for. Which is why I'm thinking you'll need to change this setting withing Windows 10 Notification settings.

Comment: @alljamin I'm using W10, the check option is there for turning on Desktop alert, but no option to change how long the alert stays up for. I'm guessing this is within W10 notification settings.

Comment: The notification in the screenshot is Outlooks own notification, it has nothing, to do with Windows 10 style notifications

Comment: @Ramhound as I said, the option is not there for me. As I said, I'm **guessing** they have integrated this option within W10, as when you get a notification of an email through Outlook it comes up with a W10 style notification.

Comment: @Ramhound See screen shots - http://imgur.com/a/9igGO I may have answered my own question in a way, although I am asking in the wrong place. Cheers either way!